# multiple thread state aware variable

Tags: java, multithreading

Assuming I have a method that processes real-time event messages at a high rate.

For each call (message comes through), I have multiple states I want to keep track of and the type of processing I do on the next call to the method depends on the current state.

Because its a high rate and might take some time to process and on a single thread, the previous call might not finish before the next one.

If I use asynchronous multi-threaded implementation (such as thread pool) for each method call, then multiple calls could get executed at the same time, and each of those would evaluate to the same state and the same type of processing would occur, which is not what I want. I want to make sure that if the state of the variable is changed in one of the thread calls, then the other threads will be aware of the state.

My question is what is the best type implementation for this scenario (use of atomic integer? synchronize?) for the case that I want to make sure that its asynchronous to handle the rate and the processing per call, but at the same time want to make sure that multiple calls to threads at the "same time" are state aware. Order is not really that important.

ie:

```
state = false;//current state

a thread                     b thread (and vice versa if thread b or thread a "saw" it first)
------------------------------
|                            |
|                            |
sees false                  sees false (should "see" true)
changes to true             changes to true (should not change to true)
|                            |


void processMessage(String message) {
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
       void run() {
        if(track.in_state == true) {
          if(track.state == 1) {
             track.in_state = false;
             //do something here
          }
          else if(track.state == 2) {
             track.in_state = false;
             //do something here
          }
        }
      }
    }
    poolA.executor(runner);
    //what happens here is that multiple threads are executed with same processing here
}

void processADifferentMessage(String message) {//a different but also dependent on the state tracker object
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
       void run() {
        if(track.in_state == false) {
             //do something here
        }
       }
    };
    //I also want to make sure that its state aware here as well in this thread pool
    poolB.executor(runner);
}
```

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: An `AtomicBoolean`? Or is your state an `Enum`?

Comment: There is something unclear; are your two threads here doing exactly the same thing? Do you have two types of threads?

Comment: Thanks, any input I take into consideration and test it out.

Comment: What are your states and their transitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `AtomicBoolean` and an `AtomicInteger`, using their `compareAndSet` operators.

```
AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean;
AtomicInteger atomicInteger;
void processMessage(String message) {
    Runnable runner = new ... {
        boolean success = false;
        boolean boolState;
        int intState;
        while(!success) {
            boolState = atomicBoolean.get();
            success = atomicBoolean.compareAndSet(boolState, !boolState);
        }
        success = false
        while(!success) {
            intState = atomicInteger.get();
            success = atomicInteger.compareAndSet(intState, (intState + 1) % maxIntState);
        }
        if(boolState) {
          if(intState == 1) {
             //do something here
          }
          else if(intState == 2) {
             //do something here
          }
        }
    }
    poolA.executor(runner);
}
```

The `while` loops read the states of the `AtomicBoolean` and `AtomicInteger` and update them to their new states - I'm assuming that you flip the state of the `AtomicBoolean` each time between true and false, and that you initialize the `AtomicInteger` to 0 and then increment it until you reach `maxIntState` at which point you reset it to 0 (e.g. if `maxIntState` is 4, then the `AtomicInteger` would go from 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 0).  You use a `while` loop here in case another thread has changed the state between the time that you read the state and the time that you try to update the state (e.g. you might read an `intState` of 1, but then another thread updates `intState` to 2 before you can update it, then you try again with the `intState` of 2)

Comment: great, thanks for your response. A variation of this looks like it could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The current problem stated by you, might can be solve with the use of AtomicInteger and AtomicBoolean.

But i guess you need some type of Asynchronous model where you are required to handle/process some messages depending of some states, and they might execute concurrently based on some states. For these types scenarios lock/synchronized is better than using atomic versions because you may need to use wait/notify/await/signal depending on some states which you cannot do with atomicInteger and AtomicBoolean. You might have that requirement going further.